# Is it a bad idea to use guava's Maps#filterKeys()?

Tags: java, guava

I have a straight use case of using guava's `Maps#filterKeys()` but I am wondering if it is a bad idea from a performance standpoint? I need to iterate over the filtered map.

Looking at the javadoc I was specifically concerned with -  `When a live view is not needed, it may be faster to copy the filtered map and use the copy.` Does this mean that iterating over the filtered view is going to be super slow and it is a better idea to copy it to another map and use it or is it better to not use guava at all?

Also, when will be the live view be needed?

Comment: It depends on what condition you need to use for filterKeys(). The result is much worse in complexity as an example when you have a subset of keys for which you want to iterate. The question should provide the full example. Also, the live view is needed if the original map changes while you are still using the filtered view (which is rarely the case), filterKeys mainly helps to reduce performance issues caused by copying a map.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not necessarily going to be "super slow."  Iterating over the filtered view is just going to perform like iterating over the original map with an `if` condition to check the filter condition.

If your filter eliminates most of the elements, and you need to iterate over the map multiple times, then yes, this will be slow compared to making a filtered copy once.

A live view would be necessary if the backing map was changing and you wanted the filtered map to reflect those changes.

Comment: In my case don't have any usage of the backing map after I get the filtered map.